# SQL Azure Error - TEMPDB has reached it's size quota

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Can't find anything on this anywhere.

Database is using less than 1% of it's size quota.  When I run a long running query that utilizes TempDB I get this exception.

Comment: what is your azure version ?,service tier ?

Comment: Latest version...S1 tier

Comment: Some more details - I seem to be getting this exception without even explicitly using TempDB....running a query to pull back ~209k records triggers the same error message

Answer (score 1):

SqlAzure places some constraints depending on your tier..I have a basic S0 tier and i did below tests to know what are the limitations of TEMPDB usage per session on my tier..

i have an orders table which is nearly 282 MB in size and i ran below query in loop..below is the test setup

```
while 1=1
begin
print @a 
print @size

insert into #orders
select * from orders

end
```

I ran below query(most of the SQLserver queries run in Azure as well) in another session to know TEmpDB usage.

```
select * from sys.dm_db_session_space_usage
```

I got quota error stating session tempdb usage exceeded limit when my session reached 974016 pages.Each page is 8 KB in size..So  in my tier,i hit an error when a single session uses almost 1 GB of space..

Comment: I'm on the S1 tier....I get this exception when I reach 141408 internal_objects_alloc_page_count...that seems much much lower than 1GB?

Comment: @DavidMcSpadden:that's strange,I will test on your service tier

Answer (score 1):

This exception is misleading - but we tracked it down to a single OR clause in our WHERE statement over a numeric(18,0) field.

We solved this by changing the statement (oddly enough) to a correlated subquery (which you would think would actually increase TempDB).

Original Statement:

```
WHERE (x <> 0 OR y <> 0)
```

New Statement:

```
WHERE x IN (SELECT id FROM Table Where x <> OR y <> 0)
```

Hopefully someone on the Azure side can explain in a little more detail - we're still pretty confused.

Comment: may be this query is using Spool or sort